# Phase unwrap on GPU using pytorch

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, scikit-image

I wonder if there is any function like [`skimage.restoration.unwrap_phase`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.restoration.html#skimage.restoration.unwrap_phase) in pytorch. I want to use it on GPU.

Comment: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/np-unwrap-function-in-pytorch/34688

Comment: @iacob the proposed solution is for 1D signals (where the problem is easier to solve).

Comment: Are you looking for a phase unwrapping for higher dim signals?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for 2D phase unwrap function.

Comment: I had noticed that discussion topic and I still don't know how to solve 2D problem.